# Count amount of elements from nested array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

In the for loop I am trying to count the amount of flights in a nested array decoded from a JSON feed. Unfortunately it only shows 2 flights, when more flights are available. What am I doing wrong?

Json feed example from endpoint

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "flight": {
        "number": "6204",
        "iata_number": "HV6204",
        "icao_number": "TRA6204"
      }
    },
    {
      "flight": {
        "number": "7012",
        "iata_number": "TB7012",
        "icao_number": "JAF7012"
      }
    },
    {
      "flight": {
        "number": "6652",
        "iata_number": "HV6652",
        "icao_number": "TRA6652"
      }
    },
    {
      "flight": {
        "number": "1925",
        "iata_number": "W61925",
        "icao_number": "WZZ1925"
      }
    },
    {
      "flight": {
        "number": "5075",
        "iata_number": "W65075",
        "icao_number": "WZZ5075"
      }
    },
    {
      "flight": {
        "number": "4289",
        "iata_number": "W64289",
        "icao_number": "WZZ4289"
      }
    },
    {
      "flight": {
        "number": "7861",
        "iata_number": "W67861",
        "icao_number": "WZZ7861"
      }
    },
    {
      "flight": {
        "number": "3066",
        "iata_number": "FR3066",
        "icao_number": "RYR3066"
      }
    }
  ]
} .
```

The PHP code example

```
<?php    
$url = 'https://api.endpoint'; // path to JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$flights = json_decode($data, true); 

for($i=0; $i<=count($flights['response'][0]['flight']['iata_number']); $i++) {
    echo "Flightnumber" . $flights['response'][$i]['flight']["iata_number"] . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What really should be used here is `foreach`. With `foreach` you don't have to care about `count()` of your array:

```
$url = 'https://api.endpoint'; // path to JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$flights = json_decode($data, true); 

foreach ($flights['response'] as $item) {
    echo $item['flight']['iata_number'] . '<br />';
}
```

Simple demo is [here](https://3v4l.org/5lFE1).

If you still want to use `for`-loop, it should look like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($flights['response']); $i++) {
    echo $flights['response'][$i]['flight']['iata_number'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($flights['response'][0]['flight']['iata_number']); $i++) {
    echo "Flightnumber" . $flights['response'][$i]['flight']["iata_number"] . '<br/>';
}
```

`count($flights['response'][0]['flight']['iata_number'])` is always going to equal one, so you're only looping twice as would be expected (two flights). My guess is that's supposed to be `count($flights['response'])` or something similar.

Comment: The `<=` should also be changed to just `<`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk_recursive`

```
 array_walk_recursive($jarr, function($v, $k) use (&$flights){
  if($k == 'iata_number') $flights[] = $v;
});
```

Live example :- https://3v4l.org/5Rp9K